# launchSettings.json commandName usage

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Everytime I find some `launchSettings.json` files, they have the following structure:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40088/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express (Staging)": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Staging"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments).

However, I can't find any document about the attribute `commandName`.

What is the usage of `commandName`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The command name maps to how the project should be started. Visual Studio uses this to run your project.

- `IISExpress` obviously indicates that IIS Express is used to start the project.
- `Project` indicates that the project is executed with the .NET CLI directly on the command line.

[image: command names]

Comment: Thank you! and what about having an own commandName? I Have seen projects with something like commandName: "MyProject-Test". What does happen then?

Comment: Yes, it used to the be the project name. However, if you configure that with today's tooling it won't be able to run your project.

Comment: Thank you again, where did you find this information? Might this be the reason why I cant deploy my application? We have own commandnames in our launchSettings.json

Comment: Wow, this seems like pretty critical information, did they document this anywhere?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: For Core 2.2 look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 11):

The value of `commandName` can specify the web server to launch. `commandName` can be any one of the following:

- `IISExpress` : Launches IIS Express.
- `IIS` : No web server launched. IIS is expected to be available.
- `Project` : Launches Kestrel.

Source Microsoft => [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

[Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is a cross-platform web server for ASP.NET Core.